# Close python Tkinter multiple dialogs

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I'm making a GUI in tkinter to do some basic calculus. My problem is that I'm not able to close some dialogs. I want to close them and change visualization by taking the user's choice.My code doesn't wait till the close of the window to do that, wait till the end of the main class. I need help to fix it.

```
class Plotia(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, *kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Plotia")
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_use("clam")

        # Configuration of the window ....
        #....
        #....
        #....
        ## Initial Values ##############################

        self.Number_Graph = 1
        self.path_file = [None for i in range(self.Number_Graph)] # Number of files
        self.columnData = [4 for i in range(self.Number_Graph)] # Number of column of the data
        self.column_x = [0 for i in range(self.Number_Graph)]
        self.column_y = [0 for i in range(self.Number_Graph)]


    def askData(self):
        # I don't understand why ChoiceData don't close. 

        self.graph = ChoiceData(self.Number_Graph, self.columnData)
        # Only when the main window close,  this two lines executes, 
        # and change this two variables. I want that this two lines executes when
        #Choice Data close
        self.column_x[self.graph.selection] = self.graph.data[0]
        self.column_y[self.graph.selection] = self.graph.data[1]







# This is is the Dialog  I can close correctly


class ChoiceData(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, NumberGraph, NumberData):
        super(ChoiceData, self).__init__()


        ## Initial Values #################################

        self.NumberGraph = NumberGraph
        self.selection = None
        self.numberData = NumberData
        self.data = []

        ########################################################

        # Layout Configure
        #...


    def Select(self):
        self.selection = int(self.BoxList.get())-1
        selectionData = SelectData(self.numberData[self.selection])
        self.data.append(selectionData.xData)
        self.data.append(selectionData.yData)
        self.destroy()



class SelectData(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, numberData):
        super(SelectData, self).__init__()



        ## Initial Values #################################

        self.xData= None
        self.yData = None
        self.NumberData = numberData

        ########################################################

        # Layout configuration.,,,

    def Update(self):
        self.xData = int(self.xBox.get())-1
        self.yData = int(self.yBox.get())-1
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Plotia()
    app.geometry("500x500")
    app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
from tkinter import *

```
class Quit:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.destroy()


class ChoiceData:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.top = Toplevel(root)
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="ChoiceData")
        self.button = Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=self.stuff)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: Quit(self.top))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

    def stuff(self):
        thing = SelectData(self.top)
        self.top.destroy()
        print("Windows closed")




class SelectData:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.top = Toplevel(root)
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="SelectData")
        self.button = Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=self.closer)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: Quit(self.top))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.top.mainloop()
    def closer(self):
        self.top.destroy()




root = Tk()
ChoiceData(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is a simplied version of what I want to do. Choice Data remain open when Select Data close.

Comment: Please don't share code from external site. You should paste it here after reading [MCVE].

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? Why aren't you able to? What happens when you try?

Comment: When I press Ok button Select Data Dialog close, but Choice Data Dialog remain open. . self.column_x[self.graph.selection] = self.graph.data[0]; self.column_y[self.graph.selection] = self.graph.data[1] This lines don't executes till I close the main window(Plotia) even if I close Choice Data manually. I want to close ChoiceData automatly when I close Select Data and then, executes that two lines.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is have an action on two `Toplevel` widgets close both `Toplevel` widgets and run a snippet of code then something like the below achieves the desired result.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = App.root = root
        ChoiceData()
        SelectData()
    def close():
        ChoiceData.top.destroy()
        SelectData.top.destroy()
        print("Windows closed")

class ChoiceData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = ChoiceData.top = Toplevel(App.root)
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="ChoiceData")
        self.button = Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=App.close)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", App.close)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

class SelectData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = SelectData.top = Toplevel(App.root)
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="SelectData")
        self.button = Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=App.close)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", App.close)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here we have four triggers to cause the `App.close()` function to run.

The first two are the `Button` widgets we create inside each `Toplevel` which both have their `command` attributes set to `App.close` which will run this function, closing both windows and running whatever snippet we insert.

The other two are a little bit more interesting, we override the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` event, which handles the closing of a window when the little red "X" is pressed, and instead we tell it to run `App.close()` which closes both windows and runs the snippet.

Comment: App class close the TopLevel windows, but this isn't my point. Choice Data is open using a Menu object in the main class. This Menu object is connected to a function(askData) that open Choice Data. Choice Data open Select Data using a button assignment to a function that when Select Data Close, Choice Data should close but it doesn't.

Comment: I edit my question with a brief change of your code @Ethan Field, this change shows my problem in my GUI, Choice Data Remain open even if I use self.top.destroy to close it.

Comment: @samuel I don't understand what you want, you want Choice Data to stay open no matter what or you want it to close? If you want it to close, when should it close, under what conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found what was bad on my GUI, in the last line, I should use:

```
self.quit()
```

instead of:

```
self.destroy()
```

self.destroy() don't let you continue your program after the mainloop of Select Data. 
And thank you @Ethan Field for helping me.